# Cap Product on Oriented Surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm reading Hatcher page 241 example 3.31 and have some questions about the calculation. Let $M$ be oriented surface of genus $g$ represented by the standard polygon. Let $\varphi_i$ be dual cohomology class of $a_i$. He claims $[M]\cap \varphi_1 = b_1$ because there is just one $2$-simplex $[v_0,v_1,v_2]$ such where $\varphi_1$ is nonzero on the edge $[v_0,v_1]$.

My questions are:

1. If label the center vertex by $v_0$ for each simplex and use counterclockwise orientation. It seems that both $2$-simplexes $B,C$(I use blue letter in the figure) have nonzero value on the edge $[v_0,v_1]$. And I get $[M]\cap \varphi_1 = B\cap\varphi_1-C\cap\varphi_1 = b_1 + a_1$.
2. It seems the cap product is depending on the labeling. For example, if I relabel the $2$-simplex by rotation permutation. The orientation is perserved so it is still the fundamental class but the cap product is different. For example, I permuate $B$ such that $v_0$ is the lowest vertex in the figure and label it counterclockwise, then $\varphi_1\cap B = 0$ hence $\varphi_1\cap[M] = a_1$.

[image]

Comment: I guess the problem is that the cap and cup products are defined for _oriented_ simplicial complexes, and their actual forms depend on the orientation. You may refer to Stefan Friedl's notes on topology, see the section "119.4. The simplicial cup product". You can find a PDF version on his site - https://friedl.app.uni-regensburg.de/privateindex.html